# How to Run an impulse response on a VAR in Python

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, jupyter

I am seeking to run a impulse response on a VAR is Python
This is my code below

```
#import the libraries

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.api as sm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#import the data

df=pd.read_excel(r"C:\Users\Action\Downloads\SMG.xlsx",index_col='Date',parse_dates=True)

#name the variables

ser=df['Services']
man=df['Manufacturing']
GDP=df['GDP growth']

#run the model

mod = sm.tsa.VARMAX(df[['GDP growth', 'Manufacturing', 'Services']], order=(2,0), trend='n')
res = mod.fit(maxiter=1000, disp=False)
print(res.summary())
```

I can generate 1 impulse response function with the code below

```
ax = res.impulse_responses(10, orthogonalized=True, impulse=[1, 0]).plot(figsize=(13,3))
ax.set(xlabel='t', title='Responses to a shock to `GDP growth`');
```

but how to I run the impulse response for all the variables
I am trying the following code but it is not helping

```
irf = res.irf(10)
irf.plot(impulse ='10yT')
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I can't understand what you think "a VAR" is, or what it means to "run" an impulse response on one. But more importantly, you do not appear to have *asked a question*. Please read [ask], and ask a specific question about the problem, ideally starting with a question word like "how" or "why", and ending with a question mark (`?`). You should also make clear what you mean by "it is not helping"; that is not an adequate description of the problem. What happens when you run that code? How is that different from what is supposed to happen?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

A VAR is an econometric model. It is one that is a system of equations. Each endogenous variable becomes a dependent variable in its one equation and becomes a function of itself and lags of the other endogenous variables.
An impulse response is used to analyze a VAR. What an Imuplse Response does is when the VAR system is shocked, and shock goes to variable first, it shows how each of the other endogenous variables will respond to the shock. It shows which variables will increase or decrease, in which lags, and by which magnitude.
A VAR with 2 variables should have 4 impulse response functions. Each one shows a different scenario about how the variables will respond to the shock. However, my code is only generating 1 scenario of the impulse response. I want to know how to amend the code so that it can generate all 4 scenarios of the impulse response.

Answer (score 0):

If you want all variables to be treated as impulse variables, just leave the `impulse` argument of the `irf` function blank and do not pass any variable names to it. The same is true for the `response` argument. So, basically, if you leave both the `impulse` and `response` arguments blank, it is going to test all possible impulse-response relationships between all of the variables. This is a good idea actually. From that, you can see which relationships are interesting and then focus on them further.